# Custom order status aren't displayed on the customer my account order history

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

In WooCommerce, I have made 2 custom order statuses. The first one is 'shipping status' and the other one is 'approved status'.

After I have changed some orders status to these two new statuses (which are `shipping` or `approved`), the customer can't view this orders on his order history page.

Here is my code:

```
function register_awaiting_shipment_order_status() {


    if('product_manager' == $get_roles || 'administrator' == $get_roles){
        register_post_status( 'wc-shipping', array(
                'label'                     => 'wc-shipping',
                'public'                    => true,
                'exclude_from_search'       => false,
                'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
                'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
                'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipping <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipping <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
        ) );
    }


    if('approver' == $get_roles  || 'administrator' == $get_roles ||'product_manager' == $get_roles ){
        register_post_status( 'wc-approved', array(
                'label'                     => 'wc-approved',
                'public'                    => true,
                'exclude_from_search'       => false,
                'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
                'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
                'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Approved <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Approved <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
        ) );
    }
}

    add_action( 'init', 'register_awaiting_shipment_order_status' );
```

But if I change the order status back to the `Woocommerce's` default order statuses (for example "completed"), then the customer can view them i his order history again.

What I am doing wrong?
How can I display new orders with that new custom statuses on customer order history page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected small mistakes in your code. *You will need to replace **`textdomain`** everywhere by your theme text domain (or slug)*.

> To complete and display this new custom orders status, you need also to register them in **`wc_order_statuses`** filter hook that is used on **`my_account/orders.php`** template that displays customers orders on their account pages.

This is the revisited code:

```
function register_new_custom_order_statuses() {

    if('product_manager' == $get_roles || 'administrator' == $get_roles){
        register_post_status( 'wc-shipping', array(
            'label'                     => _x( 'Shipping', 'Order status', 'textdomain' ),
            'public'                    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipping <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipping <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
        ) );
    }

    if('approver' == $get_roles  || 'administrator' == $get_roles ||'product_manager' == $get_roles ){
        register_post_status( 'wc-approved', array(
            'label'                     => _x( 'Approved', 'Order status', 'textdomain' ),
            'public'                    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Approved <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Approved <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_custom_order_statuses' );

// Register new statuses in wc_order_statuses (function).
function register_new_custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-shipping'] = _x( 'Shipping', 'Order status', 'textdomain' );
    $order_statuses['wc-approved'] = _x( 'Approved', 'Order status', 'textdomain' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'register_new_custom_wc_order_statuses' );
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

References:

- [**WooCommerce Apidocs source Function wc_get_order_statuses()**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order_statuses.html#184-201)
- [**WooCommerce - Registering new order statuses**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/orders.php)

Comment: Sorry for bringing this back, I have a total of 3 items in 'wc-shipping' status, i can see a filter for this status above the list of orders BUT when I select "All (10)" as a filter, only 7 itens are listed in admin's order page. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues I don't have the answer for instance… You will have to search and try a bit yourself, or to ask a new question on StackOverFlow.

Comment: It was a mistake from one of our coders that changed the prefix from 'wc-' to 'qc'. This caused the order to stay hidden in my listing. Thanks for your time!