# Adding custom order statuses in Admin Dashboard Stats Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dashboard, orders

I would like to include details from custom order status in WooCommerce Admin Dashboard Stats widget. I have set 2 custom order status which comes after `wc-processing`.

> **Order Flow after successful payment is:** 
>  `wc-processing` => `wc-awaiting-shipment` => `wc-dispatched` => `wc-completed`.

As **`awaiting shipment`** and **`dispatched`** are custom order statuses, WooCommerce stats widget is not reflecting those orders in total sales amount. The problem is that I have many orders with **`wc-dispatched`** and **`wc-awaiting-shipment`** statuses.

This is code that I have used to register this custom order statuses:

```
/**
 * Register new status
 * Tutorial: http://www.sellwithwp.com/woocommerce-custom-order-status-2/
 * */
function register_awaiting_shipment_order_status() {
    register_post_status('wc-awaiting-shipment', array(
        'label' => 'Awaiting Shipment',
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'register_awaiting_shipment_order_status');

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses($order_statuses) {

    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-awaiting-shipment'] = 'Awaiting shipment';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}

add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses');

/**
 * Register new status
 * Tutorial: http://www.sellwithwp.com/woocommerce-custom-order-status-2/
 * */
function register_dispatched_order_status() {
    register_post_status('wc-dispatched', array(
        'label' => 'Dispatched',
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Dispatched <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Dispatched <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'register_dispatched_order_status');

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_dispatched_to_order_status($order_status) {

    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ($order_status as $key => $status) {

        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;

        if ('wc-awaiting-shipment' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-dispatched'] = 'Dispatched';
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}

add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_dispatched_to_order_status');
```

[image: Woocommerce Status Dashboard Widgets]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: I'm traveling now, so can't test it now, will able to update after 8hr. and sorry for not informing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I have revisited your code as you where using 2 times the same hooks. So know you have 2 hooked functions instead of 4.

> **To answer to your question**: YES there is a working admin hook that I have just tested that will include orders with your custom statuses in the WooCommerce Admin Dashboard Stats widget: [**`woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data_args`** hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Report.html#93).

Here is this code:

```
// Register new status
function register_custom_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status('wc-awaiting-shipment', array(
        'label' => 'Awaiting Shipment',
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));

    register_post_status('wc-dispatched', array(
        'label' => 'Dispatched',
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Dispatched <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Dispatched <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'register_custom_order_statuses');


// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_custom_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-awaiting-shipment'] = 'Awaiting shipment';
            $new_order_statuses['wc-dispatched'] = 'Dispatched';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_statuses');


// Admin reports for custom order status
function wc_reports_get_order_custom_report_data_args( $args ) {
    $args['order_status'] = array( 'completed', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'awaiting-shipment', 'dispatched' );
    return $args;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data_args', 'wc_reports_get_order_custom_report_data_args');
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

References:

- [WooCommerce source class WC_Admin_Report - get_order_report_data()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Report.html#75-96)
- [Custom order status aren't displayed on the customer my account order history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693958/custom-order-status-arent-displayed-on-the-customer-my-account-order-history/39697076#39697076)

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec I just saw `woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data_args` filter calculating order total perfectly but **showing 0 Items** in WooCommerce wc-reports page. I comment out the last line (i.e., `add_filter`) Items count is showing correctly. How to fix this? Please check this [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/I2pzk5jw9).

Comment: @RaunakGupta I have tried to find out some trick to make it work… but I didn't get it for the moment.

Comment: Is there a way to add new boxes for the totals boxes (3rd line down - currently showing awaiting processing and on hold) for custom order statuses?

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec: have you got any working solution for this(_the one which I have given in [screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/t/I2pzk5jw9)_)? I tried to find the solution by searching into it's core files but with no success.

Comment: Hi @RaunakGupta … No I have didn't search. A solution for this seems to be something long and complicated, if there is any… As some one said, "think different" could enlighten you, may be.