# Setting custom order statuses as valid for payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

This function is located in the class WC_Abstract_Order (core files)

```
/* Checks if an order needs payment, based on status and order total.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function needs_payment() {

    $valid_order_statuses = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $this );

    if ( $this->has_status( $valid_order_statuses ) && $this->get_total() > 0 ) {
        $needs_payment = true;
    } else {
        $needs_payment = false;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_needs_payment', $needs_payment, $this, $valid_order_statuses );
}
```

I need to add an additional custom order status to the array but can't work out the code for functions.php to override the function, which would be like this - i.e. just with the added status:

```
public function needs_payment() {

    $valid_order_statuses = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed','neworderstatus' ), $this );

    if ( $this->has_status( $valid_order_statuses ) && $this->get_total() > 0 ) {
        $needs_payment = true;
    } else {
        $needs_payment = false;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_needs_payment', $needs_payment, $this, $valid_order_statuses );
}
```

Any help gratefully accepted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to register your custom status (If is not done):

```
// Register new status
add_action('init', 'register_custom_order_statuses');
function register_custom_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status('wc-custom-status', array(
        'label'                     => 'Custom Status',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop('Custom Status <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Custom Status <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_statuses');
function add_custom_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing for example
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-custom-status'] = 'Custom Status';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
```

Now in **`woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment`** filter hook, You can set this 'Custom Status' as a valid order status for payment, in this simple way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', 'custom_status_valid_for_payment', 10, 2 );
function custom_status_valid_for_payment( $statuses, $order ) {

    // Registering the custom status as valid for payment
    $statuses[] = 'wc-custom-status';

    return $statuses;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

It should work as expected...

---

Related answer: [Adding custom order statuses in Admin Dashboard Stats Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716254/adding-custom-order-statuses-in-admin-dashboard-stats-widget)

Comment: thanks for the help. I can't mark this solved as I can't get it to work with our setup but I have no reason to believe your code isn't correct and should work for others.

Comment: Thanks for the help, in the end I decided to scrap the plugin and use code similar to your in functions. - I have to use slightly different code for the first bit as it threw up an error with a plugin I am using, see my additional answer with that alternative code in - not sure what the difference is but I guess its something..

Answer (score 3):

As of WooCommerce 4.3 changing the line in function custom_status_valid_for_payment in the above answer from

```
// Registering the custom status as valid for payment
$statuses[] = 'wc-custom-status';
```

to

```
// Registering the custom status as valid for payment
$statuses[] = 'custom-status';
```

should work.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Could you provide more detailed answer. What and why is needed to do? Please not be offended and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer