# Setting custom order statuses as paid in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have a custom status that I need to set as 'paid', in the same sense that the core statuses Processing and Complete are 'paid' statuses.

I need to do this because WC is synced to accounting software, and the sync is unable to generate a sales receipt for an unpaid order. It works fine when using Complete or Processing statuses, but not for my custom status.

I'm using [Setting custom order statuses as valid for payment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213626/11987538) answer code.

I can confirm, however, that this does not set the order as paid. I almost assumed it couldn't be done, but I see that Woocommerce Order Status Manager has the option to set the status as Paid (see below screenshot).

[image]

Hoping somebody can help me!

Comment: You should check this filter - http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_order_is_paid_statuses/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @Martin said. You have this available:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_is_paid_statuses', array( 'processing', 'completed' ) );
```

So, you can add to it with add_filter():

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_is_paid_statuses', 'bbloomer_paid_is_paid_status' );

function bbloomer_paid_is_paid_status( $statuses ) {
   $statuses[] = 'paid';
   return $statuses;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked a treat :)